# Eval'ing html comment on img load event

Tags: javascript

Does someone has an idea, why someone else writes html code similar to the following:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <span id="onloadscript"><!-- function bla(){/*stripped*/}()--><span>moep</span></span>
    <img src="1x1.gif" onload="eval(document.getElementById('onloadscript').childNodes[0].nodeValue)">
  </body>
<html>
```

I do not have the question what it does, the only question is, why someone should do that.
Faster page load? Browser Work Arrounds?

Comment: Could you elaborate on your question, please? It makes no sense.

Comment: thx Jan Dvorak, you have been faster ;-)

Comment: I doubt there's any benefit to that. I can only think of very ancient browsers, and even then the accepted workaround is a different one

Comment: Could it be a XSS filter circumvention method?

Comment: Looks like a hack to avoid using script tags in the source.

Comment: @David even then, there's a better way to do it

Comment: @JanDvorak I didn’t say it is a *good* hack :)

Comment: @David even then, there's a better _and obvious_ way to do it :-)

Comment: the original code deletes an sso cookie after logging out. My first thought was a Browser Workaround, but never seen this before.

Comment: are there any http proxys out there, who only filter out script tags and not those onevent attributes?

Comment: @Michael even if there were, why not just write `onload="function bla(){/*stripped*/}()"` ?

Comment: @JanDvorak sure, this would be easier to understand. I see, I have to ask SAP why they've done this ;-)

Comment: It could be the code is just plain [WTF](http://thedailywtf.com/) without any real benefits. I've seen worse.

Comment: I can't see any reason not to do `onload = "function bla(){...}()"`

Comment: On top of answers above another idea here: the guy may want the script ran only if the image was loaded? so e.g. if it was (ad)blocked, not loaded because of browser settings or low-speed net or something he doesn't want to waste time running a script that possibly is in relation with the image.

Comment: @MarkKondor there is just a 1x1-gif, which should be loaded also at a very low bandwidth. additionaly, this function deletes an sso cookie after logging off, i bet this function should always be executed.

Comment: @Michael good point sadly. well... trying to find a reason but can't :) meh

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can have about this is: The script inside `onloadscript` element will be loaded **after** `1x1.gif` image loads.

I think this is a kind of "complete loading script" workaround. Maybe disguised on a comment inside an element.

You can securely and easily replace this workaround using jQuery ready:

> $(document).ready(bla);